# Convert String to Array bytes and array bytes to image

Tags: vb.net

I have this function that receives an image in a string in the parameter `imagenremito`, then it has to become a byte array and store it in the variable `imagenenbytes` then it has to become an Image and store in the variable `Imagenreducida`. The error appears when I want to run

```vb
Imagenreducida = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)
```

The error:

> "invalid parameter", "'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.ArgumentException' al tipo 'Entidades.Excepcion"

> Invalid parameter, Object of type "System.ArgumentException" cannot be converted to the type "Entidades.Excepcion"

How can I convert the byte array image to Image?

```vb
Public Shared Function registrarremitosconfoto(ByVal vac_id As Integer, ByVal id_remito As Integer, ByVal fecharemito As String, ByVal idproveedor As Integer, ByVal tipocombustible As Integer, ByVal litroscargados As Double, ByVal montototal As Double, ByVal imagenremito As String) As String

    Dim imagenenbytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagenremito)

    Dim Imagenreducida As Image
    If imagenenbytes.Length > 10 ^ 6 Then
        Imagenreducida = comprobartamano(imagenenbytes)
    Else
        Imagenreducida = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)
    End If

    Try

        Dim remito As String = RemitoDatos.registrarremitosconfoto(vac_id, id_remito, fecharemito, idproveedor, tipocombustible, litroscargados, montototal, New ImageConverter().ConvertTo(Imagenreducida, GetType(Byte())))

        Return remito
    Catch ex As Entidades.Excepcion
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: If you receive a Base64 string, use `Convert.FromBase64String()` to get the bytes. Then it's just `dim img = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(Convert.FromBase64String(imagenremito)), Image)` -- **IF** you're getting a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: it doesnt work, i post the data I send from postman

Comment: The error message is about your exception handling, which is not good anyway since all exceptions will be thrown, there is no point in having a handler at all so remove all exception handling and break on the error and check the actual error